# Tune Model Hyperparameters Module: tune and cross validate at the same time

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, cortana-intelligence

suppose I'm using the following configuration with the Tune Model Hyperparameters module with a Boosted Decision Tree Regression:

[image]

Does this configuration let me tune the hyperparameters so that I'll have the best Coefficient of Determination, and at the same time it guarantees the lowest cross-validation average error?
If so, does anyone knows what the Tune Model Hyperparameters module do using this configuration in more details?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need of splitting the dataset as train/test is you going to use cross validation to measure the accuracy of the model. No validation data-set needed as a input for the `Tune model hyperparameter` too.

Here's a simple configuration built to measure the accuracy of a binary classification. See the properties of the `Partition & Sample` module has adjusted for 10-fold cross validation with a random split.

The evaluation results, indicates the parameters that produced the best models, and their accuracy. The accuracy metrics are calculated from the cross-validation pass, and may vary slightly depending on how many folds you selected.
[image]

Comment: Ok, I found this description "If the fold assignment is not done and a validation dataset is provided at the optional dataset port, then a train-test mode chosen and the first dataset is used to train the model for each parameter combination. Then the model is evaluated on the validation dataset." here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/machine-learning-algorithm-parameters-optimize.md
But the first split in a training/testing data set is needed if I want to use the Score Model and Evaluate Model modules, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. If you need Score model and Evaluate model you need to have a scoring dataset. Then a train/test split is needed. Then it goes to train/test split evaluation of the particular model, not the cross validation scoring though you've selected the best model using cross validation.